# AngularJS :ui grid show multi lines in a cell using filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am not able to render new lines in the column .Below is my code .

```
tests = "TC2148 (test1),TC2150 (test2),TC2149 (test3)";

    { field:'tests', displayName:'TestID's', cellTooltip: true, minWidth:110, visible: true  , cellFilter : 'filterTests:this' }

    testApp.filter('filterTests',function(){
        return function(value){
            value = value.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "")
                                  .replace(/,/g,"\n");  
           return value;
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you have nested parentheses, you need to read [Remove Nested Patterns with One Line of JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/reverse-recursive-pattern). You will see you just need `while (value != (value = value.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, ""))); return value;`

Comment: please post the answer here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43114069/replace-content-present-in-the-nested-brackets
Thank you so much!

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Do you need anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Just a few small tweaks:

```js
var testApp = angular.module('testApp', ['ui.grid', 'ngSanitize']);
testApp.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
  var tests = "TC2148 (test1),TC2150 (test2),TC2149 (test3)";
  $scope.gridOptions = {
    rowHeight: 80,
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'tests',
      displayName: 'TestID\'s',
      cellTooltip: true,
      minWidth: 110,
      visible: true,
      cellTemplate: "<div class=\"ui-grid-cell-contents\" title=\"TOOLTIP\"><span ng-bind-html=\"grid.appScope.filter(COL_FIELD CUSTOM_FILTERS)\"></span></div>",
    }],
    data: [{
      tests: tests
    }]
  }
  $scope.filter = function(value) {
    return value.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "")
      .replace(/,/g, "<br>");
  };
}]);
```

```css
div[ui-grid] {
  height: 140px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-grid/4.0.2/ui-grid.min.css" />
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ui-grid="gridOptions">
  </div>
</div>
```

Let me know if you have any further questions.

Happy to help!