# Replace content present in the nested brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Input = `ABCDEF ((3) abcdef),GHIJKLMN ((4)(5) Value),OPQRSTUVW((4(5)) Value (3))`

Expected Output = `ABCDEF,GHIJKLMN,OPQRSTUVW`

Tried so far

```
Output = Input.replace(/ *\([^)]*\)*/g, "");
```

Answer (score 4):

Using a regex here probably won't work, or scale, because you expect *nested* parentheses in your input string.  Regex works well when there is a known and fixed structure to the input.  Instead, I would recommend that you approach this using a *parser*.  In the code below, I iterate over the input string, one character at at time, and I use a counter to keep track of how many open parentheses there are.  If we are inside a parenthesis term, then we don't record those characters.  I also have one simple replacement at the end to remove whitespace, which is an additional step which your output implies, but you never explicitly mentioned.

```js
var pCount = 0;
var Input = "ABCDEF ((3) abcdef),GHIJKLMN ((4)(5) Value),OPQRSTUVW((4(5)) Value (3))";
var Output = "";
for (var i=0; i < Input.length; i++) {
    if (Input[i] === '(') {
        pCount++;
    }
    else if (Input[i] === ')') {
        pCount--;
    }
    else if (pCount == 0) {
        Output += Input[i];
    }
}

Output = Output.replace(/ /g,'');
console.log(Output);
```

Comment: It's not about only numbers and text,it should replace whatever present in the brackets 

0
down vote
favorite
Input = "ABCDEF ((3) (5ab) (5a-34-bf) abcdef),GHIJKLMN ((4)(5) Value),OPQRSTUVW((4(5)) Value (3))"

Comment: You're going to need a _parser_ to handle arbitrarily nested parentheses.  Regex is not suitable for this.

Comment: @Ashok It wouldn't be a lot of work to write a parser.  When you encounter an opening parenthesis, throw it on a stack, and from that point onward consume everything you see, until you see a closing parenthesis and you pop the last remaining item on the stack.  Then, start retaining characters again.

Comment: @Ashok I wrote a rudimentary parser which appears to be working.  Please have a look when you get a chance.

Comment: someone suggested me this  ,It works like a charm 
while (Input != (Input = Input.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, ""))); 
console.log(Input);

Answer (score 2):

If you need to remove nested parentheses, you may use a trick from [Remove Nested Patterns with One Line of JavaScript](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/reverse-recursive-pattern).

```js
var Input = "ABCDEF ((3) abcdef),GHIJKLMN ((4)(5) Value),OPQRSTUVW((4(5)) Value (3))";
var Output = Input;
while (Output != (Output = Output.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, ""))); 
console.log(Output);
```

Or, you could use a recursive function:

```js
function remove_nested_parens(s) {
    let new_s = s.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, "");
    return new_s == s ? s : remove_nested_parens(new_s);
}
console.log(remove_nested_parens("ABCDEF ((3) abcdef),GHIJKLMN ((4)(5) Value),OPQRSTUVW((4(5)) Value (3))"));
```

Here, `\s*\([^()]*\)` matches 0+ whitespaces, `(`, 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)`, and the replace operation is repeated until the string does not change.

Comment: You proved me wrong, as you usually do.  I like that! +1

Comment: There are always several ways to do one and the same thing. And this is why I always ask if OPs are after matching or replacing. Solutions may greatly differ then.

Comment: Output != (Output = Output.replace(/\s*\([^()]*\)/g, "")     how does this not Always resolve to true?  doesnt Output=Output.replace() assign first because its in parenthesis and Output != Output, both output are referring to same object so this would just be returning true?