# How to delete brackets after a special letter in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

Hi I am having problem while trying to remove these square brackets.

I figured out how to find square brackets but I need to find square brackets only if it starts with @ like this,

by the way I am using .replace to remove them in javascript, Not sure if it is going to help to find the answer.

```
@[john_doe]
```

The result must be `@john_doe`.

I dont want to remove other brackets which is like that,

```
[something written here]
```

[Here is the link of the regex](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=126503)

Comment: Use `replace(/@\[([^\][]*)]/g, "$1")`

Comment: Can they be nested? As e.g.  `@[john_@[doe]]`?

Comment: No it cannot be happening in my function the data only containt word_word no special characters inside of it. Also i realised it now I still need to "@" to stay with the word. the regex removes "@" too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a regular expression replace solution like

```js
text = text.replace(/@\[([^\][]*)]/g, "@$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tEQi1i/1).

*Pattern details*

- `@\[` - a `@[` text
- `([^\][]*)` - Group 1 (`$1`): any zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` (the `]` is special inside character classes (in ECMAScript regex standard, even at the start position) and need escaping)
- `]` - a `]` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
let text = '@[john_doe] and [something written here]';
text = text.replace(/@\[([^\][]*)]/g, "@$1");
console.log(text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for regex and explanation. This works perfectly fine with my case.

Comment: @BugraKucuk Note that this solution can also be easily adjusted for use cases when the `@[...]` are nested. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43115795/3832970) is an example technique.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) `/@\[/g`:

```js
const texts = ['@[john_doe]', '[something written here]']

texts.forEach(t => {
  // Match the @ character followed by an opening square bracket [
  const result = t.replace(/@\[/g, '@')
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: This works fine but I still need to "@" character stay with the john_doe like @john_doe

Comment: @BugraKucuk Updated answer based on your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
let name = "@[something_here]"
name.replace(/(\[|\])/, "")
```